# Time to burninate the [mechanics] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [original discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/is-the-mechanics-tag-useful-or-a-problem) of the [mechanics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) tag had many votes against it and no votes for it. Unless there are new arguments to keep it, we should burninate the tag now. We have 161 questions tagged with it at the moment, and none usefully that I can see.

Comment: Has anyone double-checked to see if we have any questions with *only* the [tag:mechanics] tag? Also, is there some magical moderator way of removing the tag without pushing all 161 of those questions to the top of the "active" list? Other than those concerns, burn baby burn.

Comment: @ObliviousSage SEI can burninate a tag if we request it.

Comment: Please explain, in this question, why the tag has negative value.

Comment: @Brian That's more the job of the original discussion—I'm only bringing attention to it so we can either execute on it or continue the discussion. Please do revive that discussion!

Comment: Yes, we should execute on it, we have general agreement in the previous question.  Flagging this as a feature-request to hopefully get SEI's attention.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9!!

Comment: @mxyzplk That was *quick*.

Comment: As a matter of record: [the mechanics tag was blacklisted in September 2014.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4949/1204)

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone double-checked to see if we have any questions with only the mechanics tag?

[Is there a trick to learning the Pacesetter/Goblinoid Action Table?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13998/is-there-a-trick-to-learning-the-pacesetter-goblinoid-action-table)
[Can I default to Swimming?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11689/can-i-default-to-swimming)
[When escalating from a change of style in With Great Power, what card has to be played?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/when-escalating-from-a-change-of-style-in-with-great-power-what-card-has-to-be-p)
[What are the differences between Pathfinder's Kingmaker and Birthright?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1744/what-are-the-differences-between-pathfinders-kingmaker-and-birthright)

These were the only ones I've found.

Comment: But its arguable that some of those should have a particular system tag as well, e.g. Shadowrun...

Comment: @Phil All of these very likely did have a system tag before it was [pruned away automatically as a singleton](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/2767/321).

Comment: I've retagged all of those without the mechanics tag, though 2 of them have only a singleton system tag now; what happens if that tag gets automatically pruned?

Comment: @ObliviousSage They get the [tag:untagged] tag. In the case where the system information isn't lost during pruning, that's considered OK.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I'd say problem solved, then.