# Synonimise [rules-lawyering] to [rules-as-written], then destroy it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, rules-as-written

[From this meta Q from 2013](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2995/1204), the [rules-lawyering](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-lawyering) tag is for questions about engaging in that practice, or people doing so. It isn't for asking about strict rules interpretations; that's [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written)'s turf.

I discovered a bunch of our [rules-lawyering] questions were really RAW questions, though, so I retagged them. Then I found out that's the case for *all* our [rules-lawyering] questions, except these two:

- [How to handle a rules-lawyer player?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-to-handle-a-rules-lawyer-player)
- [How should I respond to a DM who unfairly plays the "rules-lawyer" card?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16965/how-should-i-respond-to-a-dm-who-unfairly-plays-the-rules-lawyer-card)

Incidentally that's the exact issue raised in the meta Q I linked: all the [rules-lawyering] questions were actually RAW questions, bar *one,* that "how should I respond?" question linked above. More than a year later, the situation hasn't improved and the tag still isn't used well.

We should synonymise [rules-lawyering] into [rules-as-written] to tag the remaining questions correctly, and then remove the synonym to let the [rules-lawyering] tag vanish altogether.

Questions about rules lawyers can just be tagged with [social] and/or [problem-player/gm], and the above two questions are already tagged with the latter.

**Mods, please make and then remove this synonym?**

Comment: Given all the retagging going on, is this still necessary? There's only a handful of questions with rules-lawyering left.

Comment: @Tridus Merging like this is neater - 17 fewer questions get bumped, 17 fewer questions get pushed off the front page. (The above 2 have to be edited either way.) If anything all the retagging is a reason to _avoid_ more bumping.

Comment: I would be concerned about a question about rules-lawyer problem-player getting tagged as rules-as-written (which is clearly not the right choice), but you’ve demonstrated well that *people aren’t doing that*. And in any event, it should also be clear to users who attempt to use rules-lawyer that rules-as-written isn’t what they were going for.

Comment: I think it really ought to be aliased to [problem-player], but that doesn't address the questions that already have the tag.

Comment: @Bobson After moving the questions over, the idea is to alias it to nothing and let it disappear. It hasn't been used as well as we might have hoped a year or two ago.

Comment: @Bobson Ages ago the tag was created specifically to avoid the judgement that rules-lawyering is necessarily problematic, and we already have [problem-player] for that job anyway.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie For judgement-neutral situations I think the [social] tag would be appropriate, so there's still hope!

Comment: Yeah, both of those make sense.

Comment: I did this thing.

Comment: @mxyzplk thank you for doing the thing

Answer (score 18):

I think we should do that. [rules-lawyering](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-lawyering) is just a specific sub-set of [problem-player](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-player) in the end, and the frequency that those questions show up don't justify having such a narrow tag. We have more questions that refer to, for instance, the maturity of people at the table than rules-lawyering per se, and we don't have a tag for [player-maturity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-maturity).

Comment: Agreed, except for this minutia: [rules-lawyering] was created to be a judgement-neutral tag that was *not* necessarily a subset of [problem-player], just a description of activity. But yes, it should be killed as having demonstrated its lack of use.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If you're the one rules-lawyering and you want help with that, then rules-as-written works. If someone is rules-lawyering and you're not happy with the situation, problem-players works. If people are rules-lawyering and there's no problem with that, then why are you asking a question about it?