# The [rules] tag has just been burninated (again), let's blacklist it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request

I just burninated the [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) tag. It had no wiki, and appeared to be uselessly broad, since almost *every* question on here is about rules.

I'm leaving this question here to record this burnination. <s>If this tag crops up again, we'll know it isn't the first time, and maybe it'll be worth blacklisting.</s>

This tag has been burninated at least once before, and has risen from the grave yet again. It should probably be blacklisted. (There isn't a direct record of it, but: [it was discussed in 2010](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/363/1204) and yet the usages below were from March this year at the earliest, meaning it silently disappeared between these two times.)

Questions it was attached to:

- [Can you maintain bardic music and still make an attack action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46358/can-you-maintain-bardic-music-and-still-make-an-attack-action)
- [In Hunters Hunted II, how do you use Plan dice?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45990/in-hunters-hunted-ii-how-do-you-use-plan-dice)
- [What content is not included in the Rules Compendium?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44887/what-content-is-not-included-in-the-rules-compendium)
- [Which parts of Pathfinder are excluded from the PRD?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44884/which-parts-of-pathfinder-are-excluded-from-the-prd)
- [Dual wielding with a Double Weapon and an Off Hand weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/42110/dual-wielding-with-a-double-weapon-and-an-off-hand-weapon)
- [Which system to support a grim world of low fantasy?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41962/which-system-to-support-a-grim-world-of-low-fantasy)
- [In Fantasy Craft what rolls always succeed on natural 20; fail on natural 1?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37684/in-fantasy-craft-what-rolls-always-succeed-on-natural-20-fail-on-natural-1)
- [Designing a damage system for our rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/designing-a-damage-system-for-our-rules)
- [Using Ghoul Army spell as am Oracle with the Tongues curse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36000/using-ghoul-army-spell-as-am-oracle-with-the-tongues-curse)
- [Attributes - how to determine them in a setting-specific manner?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35283/attributes-how-to-determine-them-in-a-setting-specific-manner)

[image: trogdor was personally involved in this burnination]

Comment: It had already been [killed once](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3485/321), so that makes it an undead tag. Maybe it needs to go on the blacklist or whatever our "never again" tag feature is called.

Comment: Oh hey. It was a bit weird that this iteration was so recent so I expected it might have been here before. I totally support blacklisting it, it's in the same category as [game] or [rpg].

Comment: Mods can't do that, it requires dev intervention, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95811/how-do-tag-blacklists-work I'm not sure if [tag:tag-blacklist-request] will work here but let's see!

Comment: @mxyzplk I'm requesting information on how to handle this [on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/152515); I've switched the tag on this question to just [tag:blacklist-request] based on the guidance from Shog9

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tags [rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rule), [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules), [ruleset](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ruleset), [rulesets](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rulesets) and [mechanics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanics) have all been blacklisted. Attempting to use them will produce the following warning:

[image: If your question concerns the rules of a game, that will be abundantly obvious. Instead, make sure you're clearly describing the question you have *concerning* those rules.]

Comment: Thanks for handling this! And for going above and beyond with those extras - I don't think I'll miss any of those.

Comment: Thanks @Shog9!!

Comment: Wait, no mechanics tag?  How am I supposed to ask my question about designing the proper physics formula into my new game for how a trebuchet works :)?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it should go. Vote for me, for the record. Hello, any SE dev that cares, can you blacklist this for us?