# Is there a tag for "Official rules problems"?

Tags: support, tags, rules-as-written

I recently posted [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/112458/37154). I was looking specifically for an official source, which I expressed by using the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag. However, it was quickly removed with the following reasoning:

> [raw] tag is only for strict literalist interpretation problems, not for "official rules" problems: removing to not dilute tag

I don't object to the removal, and I do now (to some degree) understand the difference between what that tag is supposed to indicate and what I used it to indicate, but I'm left feeling like the sentiment I started with should still translate to a tag even though I didn't find one more suitable than [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written).

Is there a tag that already exists, but I missed it? Or is "official material only" the default? Alternatively, should I have asked a broader question (i.e. "What is the source..." rather than "Is there an official source...") and expected an answer identifying an official source to rise to the top naturally?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't such a tag. 95% of what our site does is "official rules problems" and at that level it's not useful to have a tag. Several tags along the lines of "rules" or "mechanics" [have been blacklisted](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4949/1204) for this reason.

When to have the [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) tag and when not is kind of fuzzy... but it's important to make sure it's not just "I am asking about the rules", or it's equivalent to [rules], which is bad [because rules is blacklisted](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4949/1204) and that would mean removing [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) too. Accordingly we tend to reserve [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) for something like "super literal interpretations of the rules".

(Side note, I requested that blacklisting years before becoming a diamond moderator, so this is the kind of thing any user can request and it'll be acted on if it's reasonable; though that's rare. It's by no means a diamond moderator thing.)

Comment: Note for future readers: the [rules-as-written] tag [has since been blacklisted as well](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/time-to-retire-the-rules-as-written-tag).

Answer (score 14):

[@doppelgreener's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/is-there-a-tag-for-official-rules-problems/7662#7662) is right, but it's worth saying that some things can't be described by tags. If you care what exact sources solutions come from, you just need to say that out loud in your question. Official first-party sourcebooks only? Any published book? Third-party PDF stuff? Unearthed Arcana included?  That problem set is too complicated for a tag.

So most questions are about rules, so we don't have a rules tag. [rules-as-written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-as-written) is for "no, really, super-legalistic readings only" interpretations. Neither dictates what sources are legit; you have to specify that yourself. Most folks will generally default to official books, but if you care, say what you want.